# Magento minicart do not render: broken reference element after Alothemes upgrade

Tags: xml, layout, magento2

Got error in magento logs, and minicart doesn't render after Alothemes upgrade

`main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'mini_quote' element cannot be added as child to 'porto_header', because the latter doesn't exist`

Minicart stop rendering, i need to fix layout

Comment: Try changing the header.  See : https://www.portotheme.com/wordpress/porto/documentation/header/